# Spring Batch Writer throws java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, writer

I am facing challenge in retrieving auto generated column of Oracle table in my Spring Batch POC.

This POC reads data from flat file and loads into oracle table. I am trying to use Oracle Sequence to generate primary key for the table and retrieve that upon successful insertion of row from Spring Batch Writer implementation. But It throws folllowing error.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL
```

I am not sure I am missing anything or any issue related to oracle driver. Need your valuable inputs.

Specifications:

```
Oracle Database version  11.1.0.7
Oracle Driver that is added to Maven Proj  ojdbc14-10.1.0.5.jar
JDK Version 1.8
spring.version 4.0.5.RELEASE
spring.jdbc.version 4.0.5
spring.batch.version 3.0.4.RELEASE
```

My job.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

My CustomerItemWriter class:

```
    public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Permission>
{

private final static String INSERT_SQL = "insert into CUSTOMERS (CUST_ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,CREATED_DATE) VALUES (CUST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:firstname,:lastname,:CreatedDate)";

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Customer> customers) throws Exception
    {
        for( Customer customer : customers )
        {
            MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            namedParameters.addValue("firstname", customer.getLdapUserId());
            namedParameters.addValue("lastname", customer.getRoleId());            
            namedParameters.addValue("CreatedDate", customer.getCreatedDate());

            final KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update( INSERT_SQL, namedParameters, holder, new String[] {"CUST_ID" } );
            Number generatedId = holder.getKey();
            System.out.println("Oracle Seq value " + generatedId.intValue());
        }
    }
```

Exception received while executing:

```
    Aug 24, 2016 12:02:56 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@728938a9: startup date [Wed Aug 24 00:02:56 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 24, 2016 12:02:56 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/job-config.xml]
Aug 24, 2016 12:02:56 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/context-config.xml]
Aug 24, 2016 12:02:56 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'customReader': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/context-config.xml]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/context-config.xml]]
Aug 24, 2016 12:02:56 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
Aug 24, 2016 12:02:57 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher afterPropertiesSet
INFO: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
Aug 24, 2016 12:02:57 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
Aug 24, 2016 12:03:00 AM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=GCMPBatchFeedJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{date=1472011377348, inputFile=C:/Work/BatchPOC/springbatch/GCMPBatchFeed/target/GCMPFeedData1.csv}]
Aug 24, 2016 12:03:06 AM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [importFileStep]
Aug 24, 2016 12:03:09 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Aug 24, 2016 12:03:09 AM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
Aug 24, 2016 12:03:09 AM org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute
SEVERE: Encountered an error executing step importFileStep in job GCMPBatchFeedJob
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (CUST_ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,CREATED_DATE) VALUES (CUST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [17023]; Unsupported feature; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:943)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:344)
    at com.comp.sbatch.writer.CustomItemWriter.write(CustomItemWriter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:198)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at com.comp.sbatch.App.main(App.java:35)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DatabaseError.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3094)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:638)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: You have to provide *full* stacktrace

Comment: @Andremoniy

I have edited my original post with detailed exception stack trace. Please review.

Comment: Try to switch to a newer driver that fits your database version. In your case it should be `ojdbc6.jar` (but not `ojdbc7.jar` that is used with Oracle 12 and has issues with Oracle 11).

Comment: I see that you are using an XA-Datasource. Have you tried to configure a normal oracle datasource?

Comment: Moreover, I assume that your problem lies in the configuration of the datasource and the transaction manager. Therefore, you should post this configurations as well.

Comment: @AndrewLygin 
Thanks. Switching to ojdbc6.jar resolved the issue related to retrieving auto generated value from recent database table insertion.

Comment: I have been using Oracle 10 database for Job Repository and Oracle 11 database for target database where batch job loads into. Since I switched to ojdbc6.jar from ojdbc14.jar, I could resolve issue related to retrieving auto generated value from recent database table insertion. But I had to change Oracle Job Repository to HSQL in-memory for time being in order to make my job completes from start to end without any issue. 

Do I need to keep both ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc14.jar into my project in order to manage Oracle 10 and 11 databases ( job repository and application data base ) ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I've restored my answer, so other users could quickly find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to a newer driver that fits your database version. In your case, it should be `ojdbc6.jar` (but not `ojdbc7.jar` that is used with Oracle 12 and has issues with Oracle 11).